# Is it possible to pass a sub-query for the Default Value when adding a new column to a table?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME 
ADD New_Col3 INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_1 DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
```

If i am adding a new column that is not null to an existing table, is there away i can pass a t-sql sub query to provide the column's default value? Or i can only update the new column with query result value in a separate statement?

The sub-query is like below

```
 SELECT ID FROM dbo.Category WHERE CategoryName = N'Default Category'
```

Comment: Can we assume that `CategoryName` is unique and the sub-query returns a single value?  If so, how about a UDF for the default?

Comment: @DMason yes CategoryName  is unique and yes the sub-query returns a single integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could clarify for us a bit more about what you're doing. I'm confused. This is all that I can think of...

```
DECLARE @sqlstring varchar(max)=''
    ,@defaultValue varchar(10)='8'

SET @sqlstring=
'ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD New_Col8 INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_8 DEFAULT (' + (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(number as varchar(2)) FROM
                                master..spt_values WHERE number=@defaultValue)  + ')'

PRINT @sqlstring
EXEC (@sqlstring)
```